# what is the meaning of "wizard" in programming field?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wizard

I was reading an example on QT on c++ gui - notepad application
and i encountered the word "wizard" many times .. i can't understand what it does mean.

for example i found these statements :

- The Qt Widgets Application wizard creates a project that contains a main source file and a set of files that specify a user interface (Notepad widget)
  -The wizard generates the following code in the main.cpp file
  This is the object for which the wizard created the class and the UI file.
- The wizard generates a user interface definition in XML format: notepad.ui.

I searched on the internet and i found that it means the detailed steps to install a programs .. but this definition doesn't fit the subject of the link.
Any one knows the exact meaning ?

Comment: When you searched the internet, did you try Wikipedia? Their [wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard) disambiguation page has a section for "Science and technology", where [wizard (software)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_(software)) is listed.

Comment: Hi Mustafa, welcome to the community happy to have you join. Your question seems a bit general and thus a better place for general knowledge are Google, Wikepedia and other information outlets. If you want to learn how to ask a question check the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A "GUI wizard" is a program that holds your hand while guiding you through a number of choices / selections.

Comment: Yup. Unless you know what you are doing, without the wizard you shall not pass.

Answer (score 1):

A "wizard" is a dialog box with "next" and "previous" buttons.

Consider installing a program for example:

- You open the installer.
- The installer tells you what you're installing and tells you to click Next.
- You click Next.
- The installer asks you which folder you want to install the program in.
- You click Next.
- The installer asks you which parts of the program you want to install.
- You click Next.
- The installer installs the program.
- The installer says it's done.
- You click Finish.
- The installer closes.

This "question, next, question, next, question, next, ..." UI is called a "wizard".

It's not a wizard because it installs a program; it's a wizard because of the "next" button.

Consider creating a new project:

- You open the "New Project" window
- The computer asks you which type of project you want to create.
- You click Next.
- The computer asks you what the project should be called.
- You click Next.
- The computer asks you which compiler you want to use to build the project.
- You click Finish

This is also a wizard.